# Problem with a challenging algorithm

Tags: java, coldfusion, cfquery

I'm stumped. I need to access the next `nth row` in a query loop to show version differences between posts.

I'm using `<cfquery>` to output the revisions by group, and this is my expected output:

```
Rev4
    diff(rev4.title, original.title)
    diff(rev4.brief, rev2.brief)
Rev3
    diff(rev3.body, rev2.body)
Rev2
    diff(rev2.brief, original.brief)
    diff(rev2.body, original.body)
Original
    query.title
    query.brief
    query.body
```

I initially thought to [use Java methods](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/204-Using-ColdFusion-Query-s-Underlying-Java-Methods-For-Query-Manipulation-And-Logic.htm) to get the next query row. This does not work:

- **Rev4** needs to show the difference between its own *brief* row, and the last revision made to the *brief* row; which, in this case, occurred in **Rev2**; so it needs to jump one row.
- In order to show the diff for its *title* row, **Rev4** needs to jump to the **original** post since the first change to the *title* row occurred in **Rev4** itself.

### Some things to consider:

1. The revisions schema is one row for each edited post column; so if you load a post and edit its *title* and *body*, two records will get created in the revisions schema; one for the *title* and one for the *body*, under the same *revisionGUID*.
2. The query is grouped by *revisionGUID*.
3. It's ordered by revision date, newest to oldest; then by revision type (*title*, *brief*, *body*).

I tagged this with Java because ColdFusion allows us to [use Java methods on queries objects](http://laxmanthota.blogspot.com/2010/11/cfquery-and-underlying-java-objects.html), but it's not documented so merely knowing of its existence does not help me.

Anyone can show me a [better] way to do this?

The code structure I thought of:

```
<cfoutput query="revisions" group="revisionGUID">
    #revision.revisionGUID#
    <cfoutput>
        // conditional logic to get diff();
    <cfoutput>
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: Inside a `<cfloop>` or `<cfoutput>` over a query is the variable `currentrow`, which tells you what iteration in the record set you're in. Also ColdFusion query columns can be accessed by index, so you can write `revision.revisionGuid[3]` to get the third row (it's one, not zero based) or `revision.revisionGuid[currentrow+1]` where the value is an expression. You'll need to write some conditionals to avoid referencing something out of bounds.

Comment: orangepips, I'm aware of `currentRow` but it can't tell me if the next the next rev to diff is in row1, 2, or 3, etc... interesting on the currentRow+1... if the output was always known, it would be much easier... but I have a feeling it's not going to help here because of the unknown factors: which row do we need to jump to get the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry that I don't know Coldfusion, but it sounds like (Java) scrollable resultSet might be useful.

From the oracle info page:

> 5.1     Scrolling
> A result set created by executing a statement may
> support the ability to move backward (last-to-first) through its
> contents, as well as forward (first-to-last). Result sets that support
> this capability are called **scrollable result sets**. Result sets that
> are scrollable also support relative and absolute positioning.
> Absolute positioning is the ability to move directly to a row by
> specifying its absolute position in the result set, while relative
> positioning gives the ability to move to a row by specifying a
> position that is relative to the current row.  [(link: result set enhancements)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/guide/jdbc/spec2/jdbc2.1.frame5.html)

And the ResultSet api briefly mentions it at the top:

> A default ResultSet object is not updatable and has a cursor that
> moves forward only. Thus, you can iterate through it only once and
> only from the first row to the last row. It is possible to produce
> ResultSet objects that are scrollable and/or updatable. The following
> code fragment, in which con is a valid Connection object, illustrates
> how to make a result set that is scrollable and insensitive to updates
> by others, and that is updatable. See ResultSet fields for other
> options.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html

Hope this helps you find what you are looking for =)

Answer (score 1):

How about if you let the database help you and use the following queries to find out the previous values of your fields:

```
SELECT TITLE AS PREVIOUSTITLE
FROM REVISIONS
WHERE ID < #query.id# AND TITLE <> '#query.title#'
ORDER BY ID DESC

SELECT BRIEF AS PREVIOUSBRIEF
FROM REVISIONS
WHERE ID < #query.id# AND BRIEF <> '#query.brief#'
ORDER BY ID DESC

SELECT BODY AS PREVIOUSBODY
FROM REVISIONS
WHERE ID < #query.id# AND BODY <> '#query.body#'
ORDER BY ID DESC
```

If the recordcount is 0, this means that the field has never changed.

Comment: Marcelo, that's a nasty n+1 problem right there.... what if I have 20 revisions with 80 rows?

Comment: Isn't it only 20 revisions * 3 queries? I'll reread carefully to see if I misunderstood.

Comment: Oh, you added some info to the question, I will reanalyze.